# How to make a validation from a checkbox and radiobutton

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to make a validation where after I click in a item from the `ComboBox`without check any of the `RadioButton` it will shows de user a message. This is the piece the code that I am using to get the info from an item and fill it on `DataGridView`.

```
Private Sub cbExtensão_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbExtensão.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbExtensão.Visible <> cbExtensão.V(rbPorData.Checked & rbPorExtensão.Checked & rbPorNome.Checked) Then
        If rbPorData.Checked Then
            DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewData(cbExtensão.Text)
        ElseIf rbPorExtensão.Checked Then
            DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewExtensao(cbExtensão.Text)
        ElseIf rbPorNome.Checked Then
            DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewName(cbExtensão.Text)
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Please, check an option to search")
    End If
End Sub
```

What I am trying to do is making something with this line `If cbExtensão.Visible <> cbExtensão.V(rbPorData.Checked & rbPorExtensão.Checked & rbPorNome.Checked) Then` but I've tried a lot of things and I can«t get anything from there. Basically I want it to displays a message if user doens't select any `RadioButton` after click on an item from `CheckBox`

Comment: "AndAlso" is used to join clauses in VB. `&` is for string concatenation

Comment: Even if I use it I can't anything

Comment: You dont need that line anyway - just add an `Else` to handle cases where there is no RB checked.

Answer (score 0):

this is how I have done it for my code.

```
 Private Sub UserMsgBox(ByVal sMsg As String)

        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        Dim oFormObject As System.Web.UI.Control

        sMsg = sMsg.Replace("'", "\'")
        sMsg = sMsg.Replace(Chr(34), "\" & Chr(34))
        sMsg = sMsg.Replace(vbCrLf, "\n")

        sMsg += "<script language=javascript "
        sMsg += "type=text/" + "javascript" + ">"
        smsg += "alert ('" + "Please click on a code type" + "')"
        sMsg += "</" + "script" + ">"


       sb = New StringBuilder()
        sb.Append(sMsg)


            Page.RegisterclientScriptBlock("clientScript", sMsg)



        For Each oFormObject In Me.Controls
            If TypeOf oFormObject Is HtmlForm Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next

    ' Add the javascript after the form object so that the 
    ' message doesn't appear on a blank screen.
        oFormObject.Controls.AddAt(oFormObject.Controls.Count, New LiteralControl(sb.ToString()))

end sub
```

Comment: I just want to improve and use my code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As Plutonix mentionned in the comments, you can just remove the first `if` statement...

```
Private Sub cbExtensão_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles cbExtensão.SelectedIndexChanged
    If rbPorData.Checked Then
        DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewData(cbExtensão.Text)
    ElseIf rbPorExtensão.Checked Then
        DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewExtensao(cbExtensão.Text)
    ElseIf rbPorNome.Checked Then
        DataGridView2.DataSource = FillDataGridViewName(cbExtensão.Text)
    Else
        MsgBox("Please, check an option to search")
    End If
End Sub
```

So if no box is selected, it will fall down to the `Else` statement.